# Angular material is not working at safari especially using flex

Tags: safari, cross-browser, angularjs-material

It is kind of cross-browser issue.

I am working on chrome the material works well!

but the same page I made is not working in safari.

the height of the flex element is absent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please set in your css.

```
flex-basis: auto;
```

It will work!!

Comment: It will be great if you also explain *why* it will work.

Comment: I think chrome interoperate `<div flex></div>` to flex: 1 1 0% and safari do same attribut to flex: 1 1 0px. The last number represent flex-basis. and flex basis should has some value to show in the screen. So flex-basis should be set auto to have original length. I guess so!